# Need to add filters to a complex query

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to write a query which will help me recover class, batch, and institution details from db
so far i have managed to make the following work:

```
SELECT
    gallery.path_url AS insimage,
    r3.*
FROM
    gallery
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        institution.id AS insid,
        institution.ProfileImageID,
        institution.`name` AS insname,
        institution.Locality AS inslocality,
        institution.RegistrationFee AS ins_reg_fee,
        institution.IsTrail AS ins_is_trail,
        institution.LatLong AS latlong,
        r2., activity.`name` AS activityname
    FROM
        institution
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            class., count() AS batch_count,
            r1.
        FROM
            class
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                batch.ID AS batch_id,
                batch.ClassID AS class_id,
                batch.LevelID AS level_id,
                batch.agegroupID AS agegroup_id,
                count(*) AS num_batches,
                min(Price) AS min_price,
                max(Price) AS max_price
            FROM
                batch,
                batchstarttimes
            WHERE
                batch.ID = batchstarttimes.BatchID
            AND batchstarttimes.StartTime BETWEEN '" . $sttime . "'
            AND '" . $endtime . "'
            GROUP BY
                batch.ID
        ) AS r1
        WHERE
            r1.class_id = class.ID
        GROUP BY
            r1.class_id
    ) AS r2 ON r2.institutionid = institution.id
    INNER JOIN activity ON activity.id = r2.activityid
    WHERE
        activity.`name` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%'
    AND institution.Locality LIKE '%" . $locality . "%'
    AND institution.StatusID = 1
    AND level_id = 1
    AND agegroup_id = 5
) AS r3 ON r3.ProfileImageID = gallery.ID
```

I am stuck when i try to add two more filters batch.LevelID and batch.agegroupID
any way i can get help or someone point me to a sql visualizr tool will be helpful.

Comment: rewrite your query, it's unreadable

Comment: Which line are you trying to add, which makes it crash ? What is going wrong when you do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your WHERE clause, replace:

```
AND level_id = 1
AND agegroup_id = 5
```

with:

```
AND batch.LevelID = CASE WHEN " . $levelID . " = 0 THEN batch.LevelID ELSE " . $levelID . " END 
AND batch.agegroupID = CASE WHEN " . $ageGroupID . " = 0 THEN batch.agegroupID ELSE " . $ageGroupID . " END
```

The point is to compare batch.LevelID and batch.agegroupID against themselves if you want to ignore them for the filtering (this way they'll always be true) or compare them against `$levelID` and `$ageGroupID` values for specific rows.

Also, it's not recommended to use the variables directly in the query, as it's vulnerable to SQL injections attacks. Read about prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).